# How does one open the Firefox error console using Selenium commands?

Tags: firefox, selenium

How can I make it press the shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in Selenium to open the Firefox error console? Or is there some other method to open the Firefox error console from Selenium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no command in selenium to open firefox error console. You can try

```
selenium.controlKeyDown()
selenium.shiftKeyDown()
selenium.keyPressNative("j")
selenium.controlKeyUp()
selenium.shiftKeyUp()
selenium.keyUpNative("j")
```